# Using List correlate with three 2D arrays

Tags: list-manipulation, correlation

Working off from a [question I asked previosuly](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/147430/fast-element-wise-multiplication-of-many-many-submatrices-of-a-2d-array?noredirect=1#comment397183_147430) where the answer to my problem was to use `ListCorrelate`, I have been playing around with trying to use `ListCorrelate` again, but this time for 3, two dimensional grids. By this I mean the following:

Take an array

```
array = Developer`ToPackedArray @ RandomChoice[{-1, 1}, {100, 100}];
```

the code

```
count[dim_] := Outer[
Times,
Join[Range[dim], Reverse[Range[dim-1]]],
Join[Range[dim], Reverse[Range[dim-1]]]
]

r2 = ListCorrelate[array, array, {-1, 1}, 0] / count[100] //Transpose;
```

with some manipulating of the output gives you all two point correlation of the array. To do this we need to enter two 2D arrays. What I want to do now is to work out all triangular correlations on `array`. Hence I would need to somehow enter three array parameters into `ListCorrelate` - of which I cannot do. I have looked at the working of `ListCorrelate` which can be found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64925/how-do-i-understand-listcorrelatecontains-k-l-k-r-when-it-works-for-2-di) in a another question. I have fiddled around, and can't seem to get anywhere. The only was I can think of is to do the following:

```
r2 = ListCorrelate[array, array, {-1, 1}, 0] / count[100] //Transpose;
r3 = ListCorrelate[array, array, {-1, 1}, 0] / count[100] //Transpose;
r23 = ListCorrelate[r2, r3, {-1, 1}, 0] / count[200] //Transpose;
```

`count` here works out the average of each correlation - see my previous question for better background -. The problem here is that I do not think that `r23` is the triangular (or three point) correlations of `array`. Diagrammatically this is what I would like `ListCorrelate` to do:[image]

In the normal use of `ListCorrelate` you would only have the red and green boxes. I now want to add the blue box. Essentially this translates to:

[image]

moving the green triangle to the different positions. This is naturally only one of the possible box selections or triangle positioning as well as orientations. In my pictures I haven't been very thorough as `ListCorrelate` makes use of a Kernal, the link to the explanation of how `ListCorrelates` explains in much greater clarity. My purpose was to give an understanding of how I would like to implement `ListCorrelate` to calculate **all** triangular correlations on `array`, just as the normal use of it, is able to calculate **all** linear(or two point) correlations on `array`.